# #define rotate_left(x, n) vs uint32_t rotate_left(uint32_t x, uint32_t n)

Tags: c++

Inside my sha256 hash class, there are the following functions.

```
    uint32_t shift_right ...

    uint32_t rotate_right(uint32_t x, uint32_t n)
    {
        return ((x >> n) | (x << ((sizeof(x) << 3) - n)));
    }

    uint32_t rotate_left ...
    uint32_t choose ...
    uint32_t majority ...

    void unpack32(size_t x, uint8_t* str)
    {
        *((str)+3) = (uint8_t)((x));
        *((str)+2) = (uint8_t)((x) >> 8);
        *((str)+1) = (uint8_t)((x) >> 16);
        *((str)+0) = (uint8_t)((x) >> 24);
    }

    void pack32(const uint8_t* str, uint32_t* x)
    {
        *(x) = ((uint32_t) * ((str)+3))
            | ((uint32_t) * ((str)+2) << 8)
            | ((uint32_t) * ((str)+1) << 16)
            | ((uint32_t) * ((str)+0) << 24);
    }

    uint32_t f1(uint32_t x)
    {
        return (rotate_right(x, 2) ^ rotate_right(x, 13) ^ rotate_right(x, 32));
    }

    uint32_t f2(uint32_t x)
    {
        return (rotate_right(x, 6) ^ rotate_right(x, 11) ^ rotate_right(x, 25));
    }

    uint32_t f3(uint32_t x)
    {
        return (rotate_right(x, 7) ^ rotate_right(x, 18) ^ shift_right(x, 3));
    }

    uint32_t f4(uint32_t x)
    {
        return (rotate_right(x, 17) ^ rotate_right(x, 19) ^ shift_right(x, 10));
    }
```

My question is: If I use macros like the ones below instead of these functions, will it be a little faster? If it's fast, why?

```
#define rotate_right(x, n) ((x >> n) | (x << ((sizeof(x) << 3) - n)))
```

Comment: Only a benchmark can answer this question.

Comment: The compiler will likely inline the call to your `rotate_right` function, so the compiled code will likely be exactly the same.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that C++20 has [`std::rotl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/rotl) (and `rotr`).

Comment: But C++20 quite rightly left out `rot13`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#define macro_rotate_right(x, n) ((x >> n) | (x << ((sizeof(x) << 3) - n)))

uint32_t rotate_right(uint32_t x, uint32_t n)
{
    return ((x >> n) | (x << ((sizeof(x) << 3) - n)));
}

uint32_t test1() {
    uint32_t input1;
    std::cin>>input1;

    uint32_t input2;
    std::cin>>input2;

    return macro_rotate_right(input1,input2);
}

uint32_t test2() {
    uint32_t input1;
    std::cin>>input1;

    uint32_t input2;
    std::cin>>input2;

    return rotate_right(input1,input2);
}

int main() {
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;

}
```

Godbolt `-std=c++20 -O2` reveals the same assembly on both tests:

```
rotate_right(unsigned int, unsigned int):
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     ecx, esi
        ror     eax, cl
        ret
test1():
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt3cin
        lea     rsi, [rsp+8]
        call    std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_extract<unsigned int>(unsigned int&)
        lea     rsi, [rsp+12]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt3cin
        call    std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_extract<unsigned int>(unsigned int&)
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        add     rsp, 24
        ror     eax, cl
        ret
test2():
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt3cin
        lea     rsi, [rsp+8]
        call    std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_extract<unsigned int>(unsigned int&)
        lea     rsi, [rsp+12]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt3cin
        call    std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_extract<unsigned int>(unsigned int&)
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        add     rsp, 24
        ror     eax, cl
        ret
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    test1()
        call    test2()
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Therefore they are identical in performance. Indeed the value is inlined.